# cuda: device function inlining and different .cu files

Tags: cuda, gpu, inline, nvidia, ptx

Two facts:  CUDA 5.0 lets you compile CUDA code in different objects files for linking later on.  CUDA architecture 2.x no longer inlines functions automatically.

As usual in C/C++, I've implemented a function `__device__ int foo()` in `functions.cu` and placed its header in `functions.hu`.  The function `foo` is called in other CUDA source files.

When I examine `functions.ptx`, I see that `foo()` spills to local memory.  For testing purposes, I commented all of the meat of `foo()` and just made it `return 1;`  Something still spills to local memory according to the `.ptx`.  (I can't imagine what it is, since the function does nothing!)

However, when I move the implementation of `foo()` to the header file  `functions.hu`  and add the `__forceinline__` qualifier, then nothing is written to local memory!

**What is going on here?**  Why doesn't CUDA inline such a simple function automatically?

The whole point of separate header & implementation files is to make my life easier maintaining the code.  But if I have to stick a bunch of functions (or all of them) in the header and `__forceinline__` them, then it kind of defeats the purpose of CUDA 5.0's different compilation units...

Is there any way around this?

---

Simple, real example:

functions.cu:

```
__device__  int  foo
        (const uchar param0,
        const uchar *const param1,
        const unsigned short int param2,
        const unsigned short int param3,
        const uchar param4) 
{    
    return 1; //real code commented out.
}
```

The above function spills to local memory.

functions.ptx:

```
.visible .func  (.param .b32 func_retval0) _Z45fooPKhth(
        .param .b32 _Z45foohPKhth_param_0,
        .param .b64 _Z45foohPKhth_param_1,
        .param .b32 _Z45foohPKhth_param_2,
        .param .b32 _Z45foohPKhth_param_3
)
{
        .local .align 8 .b8     __local_depot72[24];
        .reg .b64       %SP;
        .reg .b64       %SPL;
        .reg .s16       %rc<3>;
        .reg .s16       %rs<4>;
        .reg .s32       %r<2>;
        .reg .s64       %rd<2>;
```

Comment: Not all local memory usage represents spilling. Called functions need to follow the ABI calling conventions which includes creation of a stack frame which is in local memory. If you use the compiler switch -Xptxas -v the compiler reports stack usage and spilling. I would expect that to show that there is local mnemory used for a stack frame but no spilling. As far as I know, inlining cannot presently occur across the boundaries of separately compiled object files.

Comment: @njuffa    You are partially right.  There are more troublesome functions like the one I mentioned.  As you suggested, some of them use the stack frame but do not spill:  `24 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads`

However, other functions indeed call from local memory:  `24 bytes stack frame, 24 bytes spill stores, 24 bytes spill loads`

Comment: @njuffa   Thank you about the inlining across objects comment.  I don't know much about that stuff.  So in general, it would be best practice to implement all of my functions in the header file (and `__forceinline__` all of them) to guarantee inlining?

Comment: Depends on what your needs are. Separate compilation is useful on large projects with long compile times for the full code base, or to build true libraries of device code. Tradeoffs between separate compilation and inlining are similar to what they are for host code (e.g. ABI, call overhead). Some host compilers offer inlining across separately compiled compilation units but that capability doesn't exist in CUDA at present. For maximum performance, using a header file with inline functions could still be a good approach, that is how the CUDA standard math library is implemented in CUDA 5.0.

Comment: @njuffa  So if I were to put all of these CUDA functions into the header, then is it unnecessary to use the `__forceinline__` qualifier for them, right?

Comment: @njuffa   Feel free to submit a formal "answer" below...

Comment: The compiler uses heuristics to control inlining of functions. Thus it does not necessarily inline every function, even they are in the same compilation unit. You can override the heuristics with the `__forceinline__` and `__noinline__` attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all local memory usage represents spilling. Called functions need to follow the ABI calling conventions which includes creation of a stack frame which is in local memory. When nvcc is passed the commandline switch -Xptxas -v the compiler reports stack usage and spilling as a subcomponent thereof.

Currently (CUDA 5.0), the CUDA toolchain does not support function inlining across the boundaries of compilation units, like some host compilers do. Thus there is a tradeoff between the flexibility of separate compilation (such as re-compiling only a small part of a large project with lengthy compile times, and the possibility to create device-side libraries), and the performance gain that usually results from function inlining (e.g. elimination of overhead due to ABI calling convention, enabling additional optimization such as constant propgation across function boundaries).

Function inlining within a single compilation unit is controlled by compiler heuristics that try to dertermine whether inlining is likely profitable in terms of performance (if possible at all). This means that not all functions may be inlined. Programmers can override the heuristic with the function attributes `__forcinline__` and `__noinline__`.