# Cost of calling CUDA device functions vs MACROS

Tags: cuda, function-call

I have a CUDA function `func_A` that receives a pointer to a `__device__` function `func_B` and calls it several times.

In my project I opt to have this dependency in order to facilitate the implementation and code reuse, given that I have several versions of `func_A`, in which just a small part, `func_B` varies.

I believe that instead of having `func_A` receiving a function pointer as argument, I could possibly have a solution implemented using MACRO functions. Thought the effect would be the same, code wise I would be saving on stacking arguments.

Question: Given we expect CUDA code to be as optimized as possible, how big of a deal is to repeatedly do function calls in a CUDA kernel, e.g. `func_B`, which stacks arguments on the heap. Is the time and resource for that negligible enough to justify not implementing both and comparing them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cuda: device function inlining and different .cu files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094172/cuda-device-function-inlining-and-different-cu-files) . Put it shortly, if functions are defined in the same translation unit, they will be almost certainly inlined (the NVCC compiler is very aggressive on this). Having an inline function in a header seems much better to me (in term of readability, maintainability and it should not hurt performance).

Comment: Double-checking: Does `in the same translation unit` means in the same `.cu` file?

Comment: Yes, unless you include some .cu files in other ones (which is generally a bad practice except when you use C++ templates).